# syntax error when using detect or find

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm working on a module that reads through a 2 dimensional array, matching the first item, and returning the array. I have tried to use both detect and find, however both return the same syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected == (SyntaxError)
```

on

```
result = @list.find {|item| item|0| == name}
```

using either list or detect. My code is as follows:

```
require 'csv'

class Nutrition
    include Enumerable
    @list = CSV.read("./lib/list.csv")


    def self.search(name)
      result = @list.find {|item| item|0| == name}
      if result.nil?
        result = "error"
      end
      result    
    end
end
```

I only get the error message when running rake test. Here is my rake file

```
require './lib/nutrition.rb'
require "test/unit"
require 'csv'


class TestNutrition < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Enumerable
  def test_carbs()
    assert_equal(Nutrition.search('onion'), "13.75")
    assert_equal(Nutrition.search('ham'),'0')
    assert_equal(Nutrition.search('sawdust'), 'error')
  end

end
```

When I call the module in my code, everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
result = @list.find {|item| item[0] == name}
```

notice the square brackets to access the array index 0.

Answer (score 0):

USe `[ ]` to access array element. Not `| |`.

On this line:

```
result = @list.find {|item| item|0| == name}
```

Use curve brackets `[]`, like this:

```
result = @list.find {|item| item[0] == name}
```

Your code must looks like this:

```
def self.search(name)
  result = @list.find {|item| item[0] == name}
  if result.nil?
    result = "error"
  end
  result    
end
```

Comment: I am comparing the first item in the array to name. I tried it anyway, and now I get syntax error, unexpected '=' (SyntaxError) at the same location.

Comment: @AntonySerio see my edition

Comment: Or better yet, instead of `item[0]` (and certainly instead of `item|0|`, do `item.first`.